# How to add audio to ios

Tags: html

In my website I have audio and I use the audio tag and controls and all that but the thing is when I try to play audio on my iphone (im using chrome), it doesn't play and it just says the length of the audio is 0:00... The audio file is 40megabytes so idk if that may be an issue...
Here is my code:

```
        <audio controls>
            <source src="audio/example4-17.m4a" type="audio/mpeg">
            <source src="audio/example-4-17.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
```

Comment: Is this your whole HTML file? Where are the audio files being hosted? Where is your web server serving the audio files from? the phone? A web server locally is it online? Please provide some more info.

Comment: No, it's not, it's just a section of the index.html file. I don't know any JavaScript so im not sure what you mean by where they are being hosted but I am using Hostinger hosting....

Comment: If you are using external hosting what is the URL you are using to access the .html file?

Comment: /public_html/index.html sorry it took me a while I was having dinner

Comment: So I assume your example4-17.mp3 is in /public_html/audio/example4-17.html?

Comment: yes it is and so will other audio files

Comment: Nothing is immediately wrong with your setup.
File size should not effect the audio player. If your audio file is where you say it is in relation to your index.html file you should have no problem playing it.

Maybe you could try changing the audio/example4-17.mp3 to ./audio/example4-17.mp3 to indicate a relative URL this should already be in place without an explicit reference though.

Comment: I fixed it! Thanks for your help! The issue was that though in my code I had the file in .mp3, that was the code in my editor not in my hosts files and I added that. Also I fif not even add the .mp3 file in my hosts audio file so yea... I guess iphone browsers dont support m4p files